# Improving poor network performance in Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, windows-10

I am using Hyper-V on a Surface Pro which runs Windows 10 (build 17134).  There is a single guest VM running the latest Debian for development.  This is a high spec Surface with 1TB SSD, i7 and 16GB RAM.

Network interfaces are built in:

- "Marvell AVASTAR" wireless adapter, driver `mrvlpcie8897.sys` (version 15.68.9120.47, 18/10/2017).
- "Surface Ethernet Adapter", driver `msux64w10.sys` (version 10.4.124.2017, 27/02/2017).

Drivers are from Windows Update and the system firmware is up-to-date.

Network performance to the VM seems to be poor, especially when the host is connected to a wireless network.  Please note this is **internal** network performance, between the host and virtual machine.  Traffic is **not** exiting the host onto other networks.

## Tests with ping

Statistics with networking disabled (no wired dock or wireless connection):

```
Ping statistics for 172.19.2.236:
    Packets: Sent = 1000, Received = 998, Lost = 2 (0% loss)
```

Versus statistics connected to a local wireless network:

```
Ping statistics for 172.19.2.236:
    Packets: Sent = 1000, Received = 958, Lost = 42 (4% loss)
```

Both tests were carried out sequentially under the same load, they are repeatable.  The host is not stretched for performance.  Two lost packets is unusual for a virtualised network, but 4% loss is remarkable.  Before migrating to Hyper-V the same host ran multiple Windows & Linux VMs under VMware Workstation with no issue.

A typical sequence looks like:

```
Reply from 172.19.2.236: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=64
Request timed out.
Reply from 172.19.2.236: bytes=32 time=1976ms TTL=64
```

The 2 second pause is evident as the console appears to freeze and forwarded X sessions become unresponsive.  This makes interactive sessions frustrating, but not quite unusable.

## Hyper-V networking information

The default virtual switch is used, which provides NAT to the internet.  No changes have been made to network settings inside Hyper-V.

I have tried disabling the Virtual Machine Queue (VMQ) feature, which made no measurable difference.

## Debugging inside VM

Debugging inside the VM shows that eth0 appears to connect regularly, suggesting the VM networking resets or temporarily disconnects:

```
Jun  7 21:35:34 vm NetworkManager[1327]: <info>  [1528403734.3473] device (eth0): carrier: link connected
```

Note the poor performance happens even when NetworkManager is not running.

Separately I have found that connections are reset when the host connections change, for example moving from wired to wireless or joining a VPN.  In comparison to other hypervisor products this seems unusual.

Can anybody suggest further diagnostics or a potential solution for this performance?

Comment: Win10 version? Driver versions?

Comment: Ok, and why do yo uconsider 4% packet loss bad on a Wireless? Do you have some reference information that shows it is not the fault of the wireless/interference? I have seen worse.

Comment: No. This is traffic from the host to a VM. There should be practically zero loss as it’s all internal to the hypervisor. This traffic does not touch the external interfaces.

Comment: @David have you tried different wireless adapter?

Comment: I can try with a USB adapter. However, the problem is with *internal* traffic inside the machine.

Comment: @David That's right - *when* the network card is up.

Comment: @David Did you resolve this?

Comment: @AnthonyHorne unfortunately not, I moved to another product. It’s quite possible that newer versions have fixed this.